# Accessing Other user's OneDrive public folder using OneDrive link

Tags: onedrive

I want to integrate OneDrive in my App and want to add a functionality to share data with other user using the public folder's on Onedrive. I can see that OneDrive provides the functionality to create a Link to folder and files. But I cant get the reference on how to create it programmatically. Also once the link to folder or file is created ,is there a way to access it using APIs ?

Please some one advice.

regards

Answer (score 1):

The following is probably what you're looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659732.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders